# Communicate between two python app

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, queue

I have done two app's :

1. The first one is a spider that extract all links from a website.
2. The second one  do some checks on each link sent by the first app.

When the first app find a link, how can I send a notification or something else to the second app ?
The second app must listen continuously the data sent by the first app.

I found few post speaking of `Queue` but I don't really understand how that work.

Can someone explain me with a simple exemple how to communicate between the two app ?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of ways to accomplish inter-process communication, but by far the simplest is to use the filesystem.  Have your spider write it's output to a temp file. When it's finished, move it into a folder that your second process polls periodically and when it finds work, then process it.

The `spider` could like something like:

```
import tempfile, os
tmpname = ''
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:
    tmpname = tmp.name
    tmp.write("spider output....\n")
tgt = os.path.join('incoming', os.path.basename(tmpname))
os.rename(tmpname, tgt)
```

The second process could look something like this:

```
import time, os
while 1:
    time.sleep(5)
    for item in os.listdir('incoming'):
        work_item = os.path.join('incoming', item)
        with open(work_item) as fin:
            # do something with item
        os.unlink(work_item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to save one file as a "module" to be imported by the other file. Here this can be implemented with the the `import` keyword. For example, if you name the second part of your application `listener.py`, you can type `import listener` in your other file (remember to put them in the same folder!) and call any method from the second file. [You can read more on Python modules here.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: If I do that the first app will be slowed during the checks. I need to do these checks on an other app

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0 This helped me understand modules and packages very well..take  your time and follow the code on your computer its worth it.

Comment: I want to separate the two app's on 2 process not on the same

Comment: @Pixel in that case, you're trying to implement something called multithreading in Python. [Here's a good answer explaining how to call a function asynchronously in Python.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1239252/2287177)

Answer (score 0):

A [Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) is just a container into which items may be put and retrieved, often in [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_%28computing_and_electronics%29) order. The [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) module in Python 2 is just an implementation of one that supports synchronized access, meaning that it supports multiple threads using it (putting and getting things) at the same time.