# How to await method in loop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have the following method that generates data for me:

```
async def generate_url(self, video_id):
    data = await self.s3.generate_presigned_url(...video_id...)
    return data

def convert_to_json(self, urls):
    ids = [self.generate_url(url) for url in urls]
    ...
```

How to correctly await `generate_url` in `convert_to_json`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous method call in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239035/asynchronous-method-call-in-python)

Comment: assuming `convert_to_json` was async then you would just await for each element of `ids`, I think `async for data in ids:` would work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use a [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) wrapper around the list of tasks:

```
async def convert_to_json(self, urls):
    tasks = [self.generate_url(url) for url in urls]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
```

Or, if you can't mark `convert_to_json` method as `async`, wait it synchronously:

```
import asyncio

def convert_to_json(self, urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [self.generate_url(url) for url in urls]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

Also you can try to implement [an `async` iterator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for) and use it with `async for` syntax, something like this:

```
class Loader:
    def __init__(self, urls):
        self._urls = iter(urls)

    async def generate_url(self, video_id):
        data = await self.s3.generate_presigned_url(...video_id...)
        return data

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        try:
            url = next(self._urls)
        except StopIteration:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        data = await self.generate_url(url)
        return data

async for id in Loader(urls):
    print(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked something like this:

```
import asyncio

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def generate_url(self, video_id):
        data = await self.s3.generate_presigned_url(...video_id...)
        return data

    def add_to_ids(self, id):
        ids.append(id.result())

    def convert_to_json(self, urls):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        ids = []
        tasks = []

        for url in urls:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.generate_url(url))
            task.add_done_callback(self.add_to_ids)
            tasks.append(task)
        tasks = asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
        loop.close()

a = A()
a.convert_to_json([1, 2, 3])
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a loop already, try:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ids = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[self.generate_url(url) for url in urls]))
```

Or in a coroutine:

```
ids = await asyncio.gather(*[self.generate_url(url) for url in urls])
```