# How to use networking/xhr to find the tables content of this page?

Tags: python, networking, web-scraping, webserver, webrequest

I am trying to use the following code to access the content of the following table on this page: https://cdn.ime.co.ir

[image]

By this code:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    data = {'ContractCode' : 'SAFOR99' }
    r = s.post('https://cdn.ime.co.ir/home/load/' , json = data ).json()
    print(r)
```

But what I see in the result is:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Please help me know how can I read the contents of this table?

Comment: the response of the post is not json file,and is not what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The data is not in the html content but it is retrieved via an API and more specifically  the protocol is websocket. You can check the frames using Chrome devtools and filter on wss to find the following url : `wss://cdn.ime.co.ir/realTimeServer/connect`

There are multiple necessary query parameters including `connectionToken` which is fetched via a rest API on `https://cdn.ime.co.ir/realTimeServer/negotiate`.

After you open the websocket, you don't receive much data until you perform another rest request on `https://cdn.ime.co.ir/realTimeServer/start` with the same ConnectionToken value. After that, the server send you the JSON data

The following code perform all the tasks described above and you get the data in the `result` unfiltered list :

```
import requests
import json
import asyncio
import websockets
import urllib
import random
from threading import Thread

connectionData = [{"name":"marketshub"}]

r = requests.get("https://cdn.ime.co.ir/realTimeServer/negotiate", params = {
    "clientProtocol": "2.1",
    "connectionData": json.dumps(connectionData),
})
response = r.json()

print(f'got connection token : {response["ConnectionToken"]}')

wsParams = {
    "transport": "webSockets",
    "clientProtocol": "2.1",
    "connectionToken": response["ConnectionToken"],
    "connectionData": json.dumps(connectionData),
    "tid": random.randint(0,9)
}

websocketUri = f"wss://cdn.ime.co.ir/realTimeServer/connect?{urllib.parse.urlencode(wsParams)}"

def startReceiving(arg):
    r = requests.get("https://cdn.ime.co.ir/realTimeServer/start", params = wsParams)
    print(f'started receiving data : {r.json()}')

result = []

async def websocketConnect():
    async with websockets.connect(websocketUri) as websocket:
        print(f'started websocket')
        thread = Thread(target = startReceiving, args = (0, ))
        thread.start()
        for i in range(0,10):
            print("receiving")
            data = await websocket.recv()
            jsonData = json.loads(data)
            if ("M" in jsonData and len(jsonData["M"]) > 0 and "A" in jsonData["M"][0] and len(jsonData["M"][0]["A"]) > 0):
                items = jsonData["M"][0]["A"][0]
                if type(items) == list and len(items) > 0: 
                    result = items
                    break
        thread.join()
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocketConnect())
```

Then you can get the `SAFOR99` item using :

```
print([i for i in result if i["ContractCode"] == "SAFOR99"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But when I ran your program I got `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`

Comment: weird I don't have this problem on my machine maybe you can test with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56434301/2614364)

Comment: I am trying to run the program in Spyder IDE and get this error. Also don't know why the `result` is empty.