# How to connect Janusgraph deployed in GCP with Python runtime?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, janusgraph, google-cloud-bigtable, gremlinpython

I have deployed the Janusgraph using Helm in Google cloud Containers, following the below documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/architecture/running-janusgraph-with-bigtable,

I'm able to fire the gremline query using Google Cloud Shell.

[Snapshot of GoogleCLoud Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m8GL.png)

Now I want to access the Janusgraph using Python, I tried below line of code but it's unable to connect to Janusgraph inside GCP container.

```
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('gs://127.0.0.1:8182/gremlin','g'))
value = g.V().has('name','hercules').values('age')
print(value)
```

here's the output I'm getting

```
[['V'], ['has', 'name', 'hercules'], ['values', 'age']]
```

Whereas the output should be -

```
30
```

Is there someone tried to access Janusgraph using Python inside GCP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end the query with a terminal step such as `next` or `toList`. What you are seeing is the query bytecode printed as the query was never submitted to the server due to the missing terminal step. So you need something like this:

```py
value = g.V().has('name','hercules').values('age').next()
print(value)
```

Comment: Is there any way to connect to Janusgraph inside GCP, I'm a little confused with the IP I am using.

Comment: That looks like the Python event loop was already running. There is a way to adjust the way the connection is created but I would suggest asking a separate connection for that as it is different from the original problem where the `next()` was missing. As part of that follow up question, please show the code being used to create the DriverRemoteConnection. In fact please see if this existing answer helps first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146563/gremlin-python-cannot-run-the-event-loop

Comment: when we create the connection with Janusgraph and python inside GCP, which IP do we use `graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('gs://127.0.0.1:8182/gremlin','g'))`  , is it the one that we see on Cloud shell?

Comment: Unfortunately I know the TinkerPop stack a lot better than I know the specific GCP dependencies. Perhaps try each and see which works? Are you getting an error? Again I recommend you make this a new question as I believe my answer above resolves the problem you reported where the terminal step was missing from your query.