# discord.py while calling @tasks.loop function TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, discord.py

I have 2 files the main file "bot.py"

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.all())
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.user} is now running!')
        try:
            await bot.load_extension("loop")
            print("loop was loaded.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    async def on_message(self, message):
        #some function

bot = MyBot()
load_dotenv()
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

and "loop.py" to run background tasks

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time


time = time(11, 40)
class loop(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.check.start()


    @tasks.loop(time=time)
    async def check(self):
        #some function




def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(loop(bot))
```

but it says:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
> bot.add_cog(loop(bot)) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the
> object allocation traceback Extension 'loop' raised an error:
> TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Could someone tell me the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Should there be an ```await``` before ```bot.add_cog(loop(bot))``` in your setup function?  Along with ```async``` before the ```def setup(bot):```?

Comment: @ewokx, hi, not necessary, but when I delete "async" and "await" it gives me: "ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression"
So I thought I should have added async and await, am I wrong?

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005923/runtimewarning-coroutine-setup-was-never-awaited-discord-bot

Comment: @ewokx tried to do what you sent, but didn't really help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my problem. Instead of:

```
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(loop(bot))
```

it should be:

```
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(loop(bot))
```