# get_root_node function and RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Tags: python, python-asyncio, timeouterror

I need to get access to all the nodes in an opcua server (and their corresponding nodeIDs), it seems that the get_root_node function is the way to go, though the following script errors, i.e., RuntimeError: This event loop is already running.I'm facing the similar issue, i.e., (RuntimeError: This event loop is already running), in my script:

```
import asyncio
from asyncua import Client

# asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()


async def browse_nodes(client, node):
    print(node, node.nodeid)
    children = await node.get_children()
    for child in children:
        await browse_nodes(client, child)

async def main():
    client = Client(url="opc.tcp://localhost:4840/freeopcua/server/")
    try:
        await client.connect()

        root_node = client.get_root_node()
        await browse_nodes(client, root_node)
    finally:
        await client.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

in my case, using the nest_asyncio didn't resolve the issue, it ran Into another error, as follows:

```
File "C:\Users\mahshad.valipour\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 492, in wait_for
    raise exceptions.TimeoutError() from exc

TimeoutError
```

I've tried all the suggestions mentioned here ([RuntimeError: This event loop is already running in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827007/runtimeerror-this-event-loop-is-already-running-in-python/76462847#76462847)) and still no luck. Any suggestions on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried all the suggestions mentioned here ([RuntimeError: This event loop is already running in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827007/runtimeerror-this-event-loop-is-already-running-in-python/76462847#76462847)) and still no luck. Any suggestions on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.