# Execute python async in a loop

Tags: python

I wanna use Python 2.7 to execute an async while loop.

```
while True:
    #getting real-time data from calling the API
    #make some calculations based on the response return by API 15 min after
```

Could anyone help me with that? Many thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239035/asynchronous-method-call-in-python

Comment: Also, why Python 2.7? Per the [official wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3): *Python 2.x is legacy, Python 3.x is the present and future of the language.*

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want the second execution to block the while loop. I mean, the first statement does not need to wait until the 2nd statement finishes.

Comment: You can still use `threading` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading)), just don't use `join()`. Same for `multiprocessing` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)): create a `Process` object, don't call `join()`.