# Async callbacks on firestore on_snapshot using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, ftp, python-asyncio

I have an application that listens to updates from a Firestore collection using `google-cloud-firestore`. For each update I need to do upload some data to an FTP server which takes time. Receiving a lot of data at the same time introduces delay that is not acceptable and I figure the answer is async callback (i.e. do not wait for my callback to end before continuing) but is that possible.

Imagine a script like this

```py
from google.cloud.firestore import Client
import time


def callback(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    print("Received updates")

    # mock FTP upload
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Finished handling the updates")

Client().collection('news').on_snapshot(callback)

while True:
    pass
```

How can I modify that code so it doesn't queue each callback.

#### Update

I've created a feature request at [`google-cloud-firestore`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/10216)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use one of the approaches mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239035/asynchronous-method-call-in-python)

My suggestion is using [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) in Python 3